# Materialize parallax + Royalslider issue

Tags: jquery, css, parallax, materialize

I'm trying to build an Fullscreen Parallax Slider , with a sticky header, and after it to continue a classic web site.

For my project I use some open source libraries  as Materialize for the Parallax and the responsive sticky header, with some custom JS, and royalslider.

The first issue is, when I'm trying to view my web like mobile size - verticali, it's causing some trouble there with some empty with erea. but only when you touch nothing, **as long you didn't scrolled down** even 1px.

The second - seems to be from the sames cause, after refreshing the page, **don't scroll down**, then go to the right slider section, and scroll 1px down, now, all the parallax area look like jumping. (maybe because all the images in slider, apart the first one, start from the bottom, while the parallax start from middle of the image?)

Iv'e attached my web. **Thanks! :)**

**led-shoes.ca/as**
[My page is here.](http://led-shoes.ca/as/)